# My Kali Linux is not updating and neither is it installing apps

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade

[image: update description]
Whenever I try to update my Kali Linux or whenever I install new apps, it fails. 
I get the following logs. How can I fix this?

Comment: Debian servers do not have kali repositories. I would advise consulting the official kali site instead of following random pages.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Comment: Hello Kusalanada, Actually I posted a image to make the answerers confirm that, I am running the commands as a root.

Answer (score 3):

For Kali rolling, you need to [ensure that the following line is present in `/etc/apt/sources.list](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

You’ll also have to delete the `debian-security` line, it’s irrelevant for Kali.

After you’ve made these changes, run

```
apt update
```

to update your local indexes.

Comment: I tried executing:
echo "deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list

But it solved only update problem. 

The apps are not being properly installed

Comment: What does `apt install xfburn` say now?

Comment: It says: `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?`

Comment: That means that another process is running in parallel. You’ll have to wait for the lock to be released; then `apt install` should work.

Comment: Its Working now